Как пользоваться SQLite3 x aiogram3
я не нашел информации как сделать то что я хочу:
мне нужно чтобы если пользователь отправлял текст, например: "привет" то из базы данных была проверка на это слово и если на это слово найдено описание - отправлять.
https://imgur.com/a/RfRe7Oc
https://imgur.com/a/RomKYJl

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
